# Getting the inputstream inside a jar file

Tags: java, jar, inputstream

My requirement is i want to pass some arguments from a java program to a jar file. I cannot use `String [] args`. What I am doing now is :

1. I have a java program inside which i wil run the jar file;
2. Execute the jar using `Processbuilder`;
3. Write the arguments to the process's `outputStream` , assuming the jar can read them using `inputstream`.

In my jar file, now i am initializing the stream as

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

I am not getting the arguments i am passing from the java class  in the jar file, 
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: This sounds like a very complicated solution. I would go back one step, maybe there is a better solution. Can you explain why you can't pass the arguments?

Comment: i might have to pass more than , say 3000 arguments to the jar file, so it might be tedious,so if i can write the data to the process's outputstream (the process is the one which executes jar file), and if it can be obtained inside the jar's stream, that would be one

Comment: ofcourse, i dont know wether it is possible.but i saw a post with similar requirement, but they are not specifying how the stream is read inside the jar file

Comment: Where does the data come from? Is it available on a file, or generated by another program?

Comment: It is generated by another program..

Comment: So, why not just use a pipe: `firstprogram | java -jar ...` This will connect the output of firstprogram to the input of your jar file.

Comment: In that case too, the input will be read using the String [] args right , it will good if the jar can listen to stream or something,

Comment: No, the jar will recieve the data on the System.in stream.

Comment: @Henry java -jar is executed with processbuilder, does the processbuilder have pipes?

Comment: @nikpon the idea is not to use processbuilder but capabilities of the OS.

Comment: @Henry you should read the question carefully. Option #2.

Comment: @nikpon I tried to show up alternatives since the strategy outlined in the question is far from optimal.

Comment: @Henry In this case do you want to customize the OP's question to suit your needs or do you have your own question which you want to answer because you know the answer on your question?

Comment: @nikpon I think Henry gave a valid alternative solution to the OP's problem.  Just because he didn't answer the question directly, doesn't mean he is not answering the question.  We often, as developers, miss the forest for the trees.  We get so close to a problem, and so sure of a single solution, we don't think of alternatives.  Or, perhaps even we were not aware of the possibilities.  We have all had times were we got stuck on a problem because we over complicated it.

Comment: For the record, a "jar file" is simply a zip file of java classes. JAR archives don't actually run themselves.